# Анимация модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

как сделать анимацию модального окна,что он выползла с левой границы экрана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2em;
  transform: translateX(-1000%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  z-index: 999;
}

.modal.open {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal">Modal</div>
```